# ggplot2 - split one legend (two color scales) and delete another

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, legend

I am having much trouble configuring plot legend in `ggplot2`. I have two data frames:

```
require(ggplot2)
mat <- rep(c("None", "wood", "steel"), each = 4)
feet = rep(seq(0,3), 3)
load = c(3:6, 4:7, 5:8)

soil <- data.frame(
  feet = feet,
  test = rep(1:3, each = 4),
  load = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.04,
           0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.44,
           0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 0.74)
)

dat <- rbind(
  data.frame(
    feet = feet,
    mat = mat,
    load = c(3:6, 4:7, 5:8),
    SF = FALSE
  ),
  data.frame(
    feet = feet,
    mat = mat,
    load = c(6:9, 7:10, 8:11),
    SF = TRUE
  )
)
```

I would like a plot with a legend for `dat$mat` and a legend for `soil$test`:

```
myplot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = load, y = feet)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = mat, linetype = SF)) +
  geom_path(dat = soil, aes(x = load, y = feet, color = factor(test)))

myplot
```

[image]

I don't want the legend named `SF`. Also, I would like to split the legend named `mat` into two legends, `mat` (values = "none", "wood", "steel") from the `dat` data.frame, and `test` (values = 1, 2, 3) from the `soil` data.frame.

I've tried `theme(legend.position = "none")`, and many other various combinations of code that would fill the page if I listed them all. Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: For your first problem use ```scale_linetype(guide = FALSE)```

Comment: I am starting to believe that it is impossible to have separate legend for the same aesthetics

Comment: @M-M I've been trying ALL MORNING, at least 8 hours into this.... ;)  Seems like it should be possible seeing that they are from different tables, different variable names, and different function to plot them (i.e., geom_line vs geom_path)

Comment: but they are using same aes, which is color. If you search, you&#39;ll see many examples for geom bar and geom line with fill and color, respectively. I was able to put color outside of aes for one of them and get the legend only for one. So I guess if you want to go down of that hacky road, you can add the second legend as a manual annotation.

Comment: Aes(..) argument links variables to things you see on the plot. When you put color on each geom_, you are associating the color to the name of the variable inside aes() which in this case are the same. For that reason I don't think they can be separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update** - [there is a much better option offered in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66974762/7941188). I will leave this because hacking legends with a fake aesthetic might still be needed in certain cases.

As @M-M correctly said - ggplot doesn't want to draw two legends for one aesthetic.

I truly hope that you won't often need to do something like the following hack:

**Make a fake aesthetic (I chose `alpha`), and define the color for each line manually.**
Then change your legend keys using `override.aes` manually.

If you have more than this data to show, consider different ways of visualisation / data separation. A very good thing is *facetting*.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = load, y = feet)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = mat, linetype = SF)) +
  geom_path(dat = filter(soil,test ==1), 
             aes(x = load, y = feet, alpha = factor(test)), color = 'red') +
  geom_path(dat = filter(soil,test ==2), 
             aes(x = load, y = feet, alpha = factor(test)), color = 'brown') +
  geom_path(dat = filter(soil,test ==3), 
             aes(x = load, y = feet, alpha = factor(test)), color = 'green') +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(rep(1,3))) +
  scale_linetype(guide = FALSE) +
  guides( alpha = guide_legend(title = 'test', 
                               override.aes = list(color = c('red','brown','green'))))
```

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned faceting, another hack would be including two facets, remove the space between them, define the axis limits accordingly. All in all, this can't done in a conventional way. Cheers. +1

Comment: Great hack. Appreciate the advice on how to display data. All data needs to be in one chart. "test" is soil strength from standardized test, and "mat" are crane ground loads using different mat configs (with safety factor different between the dotted lines and solid lines). When the "mat" lines cross the "test" lines, that's bad...crane falls over, and faceting would confuse. Client chooses the mat based on lines crossing. Converting from an Excel chart that's been used for 10 years. SF will be shown in caption with values.

Comment: @EricKrantz Then please don't use facets, and hopefully no crane will fall over :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can make two separate ggplots, then overlay one using [cowplot](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/aligning_plots.html):

```
library(cowplot) #cowplot_1.0.0
library(ggplot2)

myplot <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = load, y = feet)) +
           geom_line(aes(color = mat, linetype = SF)) +
           scale_linetype(guide = FALSE) + 
           lims(x = c(0,11), y = c(0,3)) + 
           theme(legend.justification = c(0, 1), # move the bottom legend up a bit
                 axis.text.x = element_blank(), # remove all the labels from the base plot
                 axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                 axis.title = element_blank())

myplot2 <- ggplot() +  
            geom_path(dat = soil, aes(x = load, y = feet, color = factor(test))) + 
            theme_half_open() + 
            lims(x = c(0,11), y = c(0,3))

aligned_plots <- align_plots(myplot, myplot2, align="hv", axis="tblr")

ggdraw(aligned_plots[[1]]) + draw_plot(aligned_plots[[2]])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried cowplot and was able to make my charts as I asked. But it uses different font sizes for each of my legends, and themes the axis labels and border with a heavy black line. I'm sure there are ways to specify the themes to make it more like default ggplot...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a better option than [my previous hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57434289/7941188) - I am sure this must have been around back then, but I was simply not aware of it. Adding a new scale is very easy with [`ggnewscale`](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale).

ggnewscale is currently to my knowledge the only package on CRAN that allows several (discrete!) scales for the same aesthetic. For continuous scales, there is now also `ggh4x::scale_color/fill_multi`. And there is also Claus Wilke's `relayer` package on GitHub.

I really like the ggnewscale package because it's super easy to use and works with literally all aesthetics.

```r
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = load, y = feet)) +
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(color = mat, linetype = SF)) +
  scale_linetype(guide = FALSE) + # This is to delete the linetype legend
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_path(data = soil, aes(x = load, y = feet, color = as.factor(test))) +
  scale_color_manual("Test", values = c('red','brown','green'))
```

[image]